# написать запрос используя fetch метод

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, curl

Для отправки запросов на сервер использовал утилиту `CURL`, но наткнулся на более удобный способ,- использую `consol`.
Отправка запросов методом `fetch`, разобрался, как писать запросы к `API`, но не могу разобраться с одним запросом:

`curl -X POST --user 'auth:auth' -d 'grant_type=password&username=peter@example.com&password=password' http://localhost:8000/authserver/oauth/token`

как написать этот запрос используя `fetch` метод?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
fetch('/authserver/oauth/token', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('auth:auth'),
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }),
  body: 'grant_type=password&username=peter@example.com&password=password'
})
.then(r => r.json()) // подразумевается, что ответ - корректный JSON.
.then(r => console.log(r)); // какая-то обработка результата.
```

Документация по [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Большое спасибо !!!!